# Swift 3 - Isolate a function

Tags: swift3

I need a function, which can only be called once, and you have to wait until the next one can be executed

```
private func receive(){
    var inputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: BUFFER_MAX);
    let bytesRead = self.inputStream.read(&inputBuffer, maxLength: BUFFER_MAX);

    if(bytesRead > 0){
        let string = convertToString(byteArray: inputBuffer, length: bytesRead);
        // Call if previous is finished
        CommandHandler.convert(string);

    }
}
```

I have tested something like this:

```
var dispQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "commandConvert")
...
private func convert(){
    dispQueue.sync {
         ...

    }
}
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you can explain the broader problem you're trying to solve and we can show you patterns to achieve this. This smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you're asking us to help you on your proposed solution rather than the underlying problem.

Comment: For Example, if i get mesages from 0 to 100 in packages of 0...3, 4...7, 8...11, ...   I will get 8...11 before i get 4...7. In func convert.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue the other day.

You can solve this using a callback or a Dispatch Group. Here is the Dispatch Group solution:

```
class test {
            let myDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            func receive () {
                myDispatchGroup.enter()
                var inputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: BUFFER_MAX);
                let bytesRead = self.inputStream.read(&inputBuffer, maxLength: BUFFER_MAX);
                if(bytesRead > 0){
                      let string = convertToString(byteArray: inputBuffer, length: bytesRead);
                      myDispatchGroup.leave()
                }
                 myDispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                        // Call if previous is finished
                        CommandHandler.convert(string);
                }
             }
```